# Deployment of application using spring-data-jpa fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a simple web application which is deploying and working fine in Apache Tomcat 8.0. As soon as I add the spring-data-jpa dependency, it fails. No changes in code until now.

```
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the output:

```
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/student-exchange
OK - Undeployed application at context path /student-exchange
In-place deployment at /Users/Vincent/NetBeansProjects/student-exchange/target/StudentsApplication
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2Fzg%2Fb2w5j60d2x7cy12hxn998r480000gs%2FT%2Fcontext8080124463540341991.xml&path=/student-exchange
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /student-exchange but context failed to start
```

I can't find out what the cause is here. Are there further details which are not shown by Netbeans?

Comment: If you deploy outside Netbeans, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It was actually right there in a Tomcat log file which was not shown in an output window.

```
    <spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Spring version of 2.2.5 or better should be used. Now using 2.2.9 and is deploying and working find. Even JPA repositories all working.

I'm still not sure where I can find compatibility lists with clearly documented Spring versions compatible with other Spring projects. On Spring Data JPA, I didn't find anything about the minimum required version.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually: consider the dependency versions stated in the library POMs the lower version boundary. For the current Spring Data Dijkstra release train (including Spring Data JPA 1.6) it's Spring 3.2.9.